# Check if user is logged in as admin mode in Windows 7 Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, administrator

I need to change a setting for a user through there browser, a user normally right clicks on Chrome and selects opens in administrator mode, is it possible to automatically check if a user is logged in as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Signed Java Applet was my fix, I copy a file into the clients temp folder on there pc and if that's successful, then I have admin rights to the clients browser.